# Bootstrap and my CSS clashed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing my project for web development and my friend was assigned to do the nav bar. But after i completed my website and pasted his nav bar codes into my codes. It clashed with my bootstrap and thus not displaying correctly. I tried searching for solutions like pasting the link ref after the bootstrap but still up to no avail.

I'll put the CSS code and HTML code here. I'm guessing the classes clashed?

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="donation" border= href="#donate">DONATE</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#events" id="maintopic" class="dropbtn">EVENTS</a>
        <div id="specificdays" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">World Environment Day</a>
            <a href="#">World Ocean Day</a>
            <a href="#">World Clean Up Day</a>
            <a href="#">World Day to combat Desertification and Drought </a>
        </div>
     </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="maintopic" class="dropbtn">PROJECTS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Reward System</a>
            <a href="#">Comic Strips &amp; Posters</a>
            <a href="#">Make A Pledge</a>
            <a href="#">Why a Greenboy</a>
            <a href="#">Donate to a cause</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a id="maintopic" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li id="logo"><a href="#home"><img src="eugene.png" class="logo"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

/*CSS*/

```
*{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
#mainpage{
    width:100%;
    height:650px;
}
#logo{
    float:left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav{
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
}
li {
    float: right;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right:40px;
    padding-top:10px;
    display:block;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:quicksand;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
#maintopic{
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size:13px;
}
.donation{
    border:1;
    border-size:1px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size:13px;
    border-color:#333;
    border-style:solid;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-color:white;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.donation:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
}
#maintopic:hover{
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}

li .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    width:128px;
}
#specificdays a{
    width:200px;
}
#specificdays a:hover{
    width:190px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color:#ddd ;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}
.navbar{
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
}
.logo{
    width:140px;
    height:60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-bottom:-10px;
}
```

Comment: change the navbar class in `HTML` and `CSS` files. Make them unique then it will not clash simple as that

Comment: Your class names are the problem.Be more specific when you are naming a class.

Comment: @JayantSingh , i did exactly as that but that didnt work out well. Although some features were only working.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename your class with any unique name which will not be in `Bootstrap`.For that you can add your website name with class or anything

```
<nav class="your-theme-navbar">
<ul>
  <li><a class="donation" border= href="#donate">DONATE</a></li>
  <li class="your-theme-dropdown">
    <a href="#events" id="maintopic" class="dropbtn">EVENTS</a>
    <div id="specificdays" class="your-theme-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">World Environment Day</a>
        <a href="#">World Ocean Day</a>
        <a href="#">World Clean Up Day</a>
        <a href="#">World Day to combat Desertification and Drought </a>
    </div>
 </li>
  <li class="your-theme-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="maintopic" class="dropbtn">PROJECTS</a>
    <div class="your-theme-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Reward System</a>
        <a href="#">Comic Strips &amp; Posters</a>
        <a href="#">Make A Pledge</a>
        <a href="#">Why a Greenboy</a>
        <a href="#">Donate to a cause</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a id="maintopic" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li id="logo"><a href="#home"><img src="eugene.png" class="your-theme-logo"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and change these classes in `CSS` also

```
*{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
#mainpage{
    width:100%;
    height:650px;
}
#logo{
    float:left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav{
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
}
li {
    float: right;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right:40px;
    padding-top:10px;
    display:block;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:quicksand;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
#maintopic{
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size:13px;
}
.donation{
    border:1;
    border-size:1px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size:13px;
    border-color:#333;
    border-style:solid;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-color:white;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.donation:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
}
#maintopic:hover{
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}

li .your-theme-dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.your-theme-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.your-theme-dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    width:128px;
}
#specificdays a{
    width:200px;
}
#specificdays a:hover{
    width:190px;
}

.your-theme-dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color:#ddd ;
}

.your-theme-dropdown:hover .your-theme-dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}
.your-theme-navbar{
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
}
.your-theme-logo{
    width:140px;
    height:60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-bottom:-10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro. But when i put the bootstrap link - <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">  . It does not function normally, like the text decoration of the <li> . @Jayant Singh

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your defined classes, for example .navbar class in your css file is already included in css file of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use some css of bootstrap and some custom css then just write new class nearby navbar class and target all navbar css with that new class
example

```css
*{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
#mainpage{
    width:100%;
    height:650px;
}
#logo{
    float:left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav.custom-navbar{
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
}
.custom-navbar ul li {
    float: right;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right:40px;
    padding-top:10px;
    display:block;
}

.custom-navbar ul li a,.custom-navbar ul li a.dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:quicksand;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
#maintopic{
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size:13px;
}
.donation{
    border:1;
    border-size:1px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size:13px;
    border-color:#333;
    border-style:solid;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-color:white;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.donation:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
}
#maintopic:hover{
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}

.custom-navbar ul li .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.custom-navbar ul li .dropdown .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.custom-navbar ul li .dropdown .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    width:128px;
}
#specificdays a{
    width:200px;
}
#specificdays a:hover{
    width:190px;
}

.custom-navbar ul li .dropdown .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color:#ddd ;
}

.custom-navbar ul li .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}
.custom-navbar.navbar{
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
}
.logo{
    width:140px;
    height:60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-bottom:-10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar custom-navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="donation" border= href="#donate">DONATE</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#events" id="maintopic" class="dropbtn">EVENTS</a>
        <div id="specificdays" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">World Environment Day</a>
            <a href="#">World Ocean Day</a>
            <a href="#">World Clean Up Day</a>
            <a href="#">World Day to combat Desertification and Drought </a>
        </div>
     </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="maintopic" class="dropbtn">PROJECTS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Reward System</a>
            <a href="#">Comic Strips &amp; Posters</a>
            <a href="#">Make A Pledge</a>
            <a href="#">Why a Greenboy</a>
            <a href="#">Donate to a cause</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a id="maintopic" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li id="logo"><a href="#home"><img src="eugene.png" class="logo"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm sorry bro , but this didn't help.  You should try run the codes haha

Comment: somehow my snippet is not working but solution is right that only just you have to add class nearby navbar and just target all the css with your class and navbarclass